# Multivariable linear regression in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, statistics, regression

I am trying to perform multivariable linear regression with a single dependent variable `Y` and two independent variables `x1`, `x2`.

This is simply an OLS regression with an additional dependent variable:

`Y = b0 + b1 x1 + b2 x2`

I need to also calculate the correlation coefficient `R^2` for this relationship.

Every NPM package i've tested either has support for only one dependent variable, or they have support for multi*variate* regression, which is distinct to multi*variable* regression.

If an existing package does not exist, i'm ok with trying to calculate the coefficients without one. For example `slope`, `intercept` and `R^2` for a single `x` and `Y` set can be determined with the following:

```
function linearRegression(y,x){
        var lr = {};
        var n = y.length;
        var sum_x = 0;
        var sum_y = 0;
        var sum_xy = 0;
        var sum_xx = 0;
        var sum_yy = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

            sum_x += x[i];
            sum_y += y[i];
            sum_xy += (x[i]*y[i]);
            sum_xx += (x[i]*x[i]);
            sum_yy += (y[i]*y[i]);
        } 

        lr['slope'] = (n * sum_xy - sum_x * sum_y) / (n*sum_xx - sum_x * sum_x);
        lr['intercept'] = (sum_y - lr.slope * sum_x)/n;
        lr['r2'] = Math.pow((n*sum_xy - sum_x*sum_y)/Math.sqrt((n*sum_xx-sum_x*sum_x)*(n*sum_yy-sum_y*sum_y)),2);

        return lr;
}
```

But I am unsure how I can adapt this for multiple dependent variables.